# Роутинг в Symfony для bundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Разбираюсь с Symfony 3.4, но не могу понять как добавить маршрут для контроллера.

Добавил бандл в routing.yml

`user:
    resource: '@UserBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation`

В бандле User есть папка Controller, а в ней создал LoginController.php

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller;


use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Class LoginController
 *
 * @package UserBundle\Controller
 *
 * @Route("/login", name="login_")
 */
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Matches / exactly
     *
     * @Route("/", name="login")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return new Response(
            'Welcome '
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['Content-type' => 'application/json',]
        );
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь переходиь:
my.local/user/login
my.local/user/

Получаю 404. Почему? Подскажите, пожалуйтса, как решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Symfony есть возможность формировать роутинг через конфигурационный файл и аннотациями. И в том и в том случае необходимо конфигурировать config/routes.yaml.

Запись вида:

```
user:
    resource: '@UserBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Говорит о том что Вы используете тип аннотации, а user тут фигурирует только как название роута, и не является частью урла.

`@Route("/", name="login")` означает, ваш URL ссылается на корень `/`, а название роута `login`. Поэтому Ваш путь будет просто `http://my.local/`.

Если вы хотите сформировать урл таким обраазом: http://my.local/login, то нужно так и писать в роуте.

```
@Route("/login", name="login")
```

Если выходите выделить группу роутов user, тогда можно изменить `config/routes.yaml` добавив в него поле `path`

```
user:
    resource: '@UserBundle/Controller/'
    path: /user
    type: annotation
```

Тогда урл будет формироваться так  `my.local/user/login`

Comment: За такой ответ благодарю! yml файл добавил path, вот отрывок из контроллера, но всё равно 404

class LoginController extends Controller 

    /**
     * Matches /login exactly
     *
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function index()

Comment: Я правильно понял не работает с path?

Comment: попробуйте вместо path поставить  `prefix: /user` в routes.yaml

Comment: изменил на префикс, тоже не работает, 404 ошибка. 
Я над название класса ничего не добавлял, а вот над методом index прописл @Route("/login", name="login")

Comment: Похоже я ошибаюсь и префиксы можно поставить только аннотациями перед классом контроллера. `@Route("/user") class LoginController`

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось кеш нужно очистить.

Comment: а тогда понятно)) с path все работает?

Comment: Я поставил prefix в yml файле чтобы для всех был user путь, спасибо Вам за помощь:)

Comment: Пожалуйста ))))